# RJS error in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, rjs

I am working in rails 2.3.8 and I got following rjs error in my rails application.

```
RJS error:
TypeError: $("#create_event_dialog") is nul
```

Then I click ok, then come another one.

```
Element.update("create_event", "<form action=\"/countries\" class=\"new_country\"   id=\"new_country\" method=\"post\" onsubmit=\"new Ajax.Request('/countries', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, parameters:Form.serialize(this)}); return false;\"><div style=\"margin:0;padding:0;display:inline\"><input name=\"authenticity_token\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"qWXCu2zMmlMhJG+GRf35kMbAIfzYAtFBee142ThmmMw=\" /></div>\n <p>\n    <label for=\"country_name\">Name</label><br />\n    <input id=\"country_name\" name=\"country[name]\" size=\"30\" type=\"text\" />\n  </p>\n  <p>\n    <input id=\"country_submit\" name=\"commit\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Create\" />\n  </p>\n</form>");
$('#create_event_dialog').dialog({
    title: 'New Event',
    modal: true,
    width: 500,
    close: function(event, ui) { $('#create_event_dialog').dialog('destroy') }

});
```

Here's my code...

```
<%= link_to_remote 'Add new countries', :url => {:controller => 'countries', :action => 'new'} %>

<div id = "create_event_dialog" style ="display:none;">
<div id = "create_event"></div>
</div>
```

new.js.rjs::

```
page.replace_html 'create_event', :partial => 'form'
page<< "$('#create_event_dialog').dialog({
    title: 'New Event',
    modal: true,
    width: 500,
    close: function(event, ui) { $('#create_event_dialog').dialog('destroy') }

});"
```

create.js.rjs

```
if @country
if @country.save

page<<"$('#create_event_dialog').dialog('destroy')"
else
page.alert @country.errors.full_messages(',').join("\n")
end
end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%remote_form_for @country, :url => {:controller => 'countries', :action => 'create' } do |f| %>
<p>
<%= f.label :name %><br />
<%= f.text_field :name %>
</p>
<p>
<%= f.submit 'Create' %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

Can anybody help me? Why did I get this error?

Comment: Why should I get this error box? I created create_event div id in my application. There are no errors and **200** **ok** in firebug... How should I fix this? please help me to correct this. Is rjs not suitable for this?

Comment: What is your prototype/jquery setup? Prototype is the default for rails 2 unless you've worked around that. `$('#create_event_dialog')` is a bad selector for prototype, it would be `$('create_event_dialog')` so you would see the null RJS error you're seeing with that.